# How to dynamically set JAVA_HOME in Jenkins docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline is running on a docker agent containing several jdks. The specific jdk version to use to build a project is chosen within the pipeline description.
(As I am using JTE plugin (https://jenkinsci.github.io/templating-engine-plugin/2.5/), this is done by passing the jdk version to use via the JTE `config` variable to the libraries used to define the jenkins pipeline.)

The end result at the moment (once the variables are resolved) is that the maven commands look as followed:

```
sh("env JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11 /opt/maven-3/bin/mvn compile")
```

where:
`/opt/jdk-11` is the folder in the docker agent container where the jdk-11 is installed (there is also the possibility to choose jdk-17, and other)
`/opt/maven-3/bin/mvn` is the folder in the docker agent container where maven is installed

Is it be possible, instead of declaring `env JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11` in the command line, to declare it as a environment variable in the docker agent dynamically so that for all steps

```
sh('echo $JAVA_HOME')
```

would return `/opt/jdk-11`

and the maven command line would look like:

```
sh("/opt/maven-3/bin/mvn compile")
```

?

Comment: Use the [pipeline tools](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#supported-tools) syntax.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to use the pipeline tools with JTE plugins (https://jenkinsci.github.io/templating-engine-plugin/2.5/)

Comment: No idea; never used JTE, but seems like a reasonable proposition it should if it generates executable pipelines.

Comment: @vivi i wonder if you were able to solve that issue, i am currenlty stuck there as well, please do drop a response if you could fix it, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution has been found yet. I have just kept the env variable in the sh command until now.